# mysql a subquery in the select statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query where the users are ordered by the promo code they used and tells me out of those users how many had the free plan and how many had a paid plan.  Here is my attempt at it.

```
select count(refer) as promo, (count(plan)
    from users
    where plan = 'free'
) as free, (count(plan)
    from users
    where plan <> 'free'
) as pay from users
where refer <> ''
group by refer
```

This does not work, but I am unsure what to change to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through function CASE

```
select count(refer) as promo, 
count(case when plan = 'free' then 1 end) as free
count(case when plan <> 'free' then 1 end) as pay
from users
where refer <> ''
group by refer
```

Comment: Thanks, what does then 1 end for?

Comment: Simply a unit symbol, this is the context for the count function